# Какое сообщение WinAPI заставляет модальную форму моргать при попытке переключиться на другую форму?

Tags: delphi, winapi, vcl

Какое сообщение WinAPI заставляет модальную форму моргать при попытке переключиться на другую форму приложения не закрыв модальную? Как отловить это событие?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-ncactivate ?

Comment: збс пошло))!!!. спс